# Don't-repeat-yourself git revision range syntax?

Tags: git

Suppose `S` is the SHA of a git commit.

How can we express the range `S^..S` without the annoyance of repeating S?

In other words, "give me the one-commit range ending in commit S".

(And is there way which generalizes to N commits ending in S?)

I read `man gitrevisions` backwards and forwards; didn't find anything.

Comment: I don't think you can (other than via shell script tricks anyway, using variables and/or aliases to do the repetitive part).

Comment: @torek Perhaps with the shell scoped env syntax:  `X=<sha> git command $X^..$X`.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem or help us to help you

Answer (score 4):

I think you are searching for `<tree-ish>^!`

See [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltrevgtemegemHEADem) documentation for details:

Repeated for convenience:

> `<rev>^!, e.g. HEAD^!`
>
> A suffix `^` followed by an exclamation mark is the same as giving commit `<rev>` and then all its parents prefixed with `^` to exclude them (and their ancestors).

Not as easy to understand, but I am quite certain it is what you are searching for.

*But I don't see a generalized way to do this.*

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap this up into a tidy little git alias:

```
git config --global alias.range '!bash -c "git $1 ${2-HEAD}~$3..${2-HEAD}" -'
```

Breaking down:

1. Create the global alias range

   ```
   git config --global alias.range
   ```
2. Call an external bash command

   ```
   '!bash -c "<command>" -'
   ```
3. Call git with the first parameter as the command

   ```
   git $1
   ```
4. Then build our range out of the second and third parameters

   - `${2-HEAD}` uses the second parameter or defaults to HEAD of none is
     supplied
   - `$3` is the number of commits you want, will be empty if the parameter is not supplied.
     supplied

     ```
     ${2-HEAD}~$3..${2-HEAD}
     ```

Example Usage:

```
`git range log 4ab9f0d 4`
```